# Multiple Left Joins in Spark Dataframe with same table without Unique Column Error

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a Main Dataframe - seasonsDF, Left-Joined with Key-Value DF - listvaluesDF, multiple times

```
val seasonFinal1DF = seasonsDF.join(paletteDF, seasonsDF("Palette") === paletteDF("id"), "left_outer")
                              .join(flextypeDF, seasonsDF("flextype") === listvaluesDF("key"), "left_outer")
                              .join(listvaluesDF, seasonsDF("Year") === listvaluesDF("key"), "left_outer")
                              .join(listvaluesDF, seasonsDF("Set Week") === listvaluesDF("key"), "left_outer")
```

Now when I try to access Final - seasonFinal1DF , its throwing **Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'id' in table 'SeasonLeft' is specified more than once.**

is there any way I can alias the final columns the same DF being joined multiple times ?

Suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean "alias" as in adding a suffix to the columns before joining? 
if yes, you could try going through the columns of the dataframe and renaming them before you join the df

```
listvaluesDF.columns.foldLeft(listvaluesDF) {
     case(df,col) => df.withColumnRenamed(col, col+"suffix") }
```

if no, then maybe you could clarify what you're expecting or give an example of you're suggesting as a solution!